# Getting status 500 when using angularjs $http to get data from server

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on an asp.net mvc application and I am using Entity Framework and AngularJS in it. I am using AngularJS's `$http` service to call an action method and retrieve data from the server. The correct data is retrieved from the server (I confirmed this by debugging), but somehow an error occurs after the action method returns the retrieved data and the error callback function is fired instead of the success callback function. And then I get a status 500 in the browser's console.

Here are the involved blocks of codes:

(From angularjs controller)

```
    $http({
        url: rootUrl + "User/GetUser",//'@Url.Action("GetUser","User")',
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            uname: $scope.username,
            pword: $scope.pass
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        alert('success!');
        $scope.user = response.data;
        if ($scope.user.Fullname != undefined) {
            $http({
                url: rootUrl + "Session/Set",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    "key": "curr_user",
                    "value": JSON.stringify($scope.user)
                }
            });

            window.location.href = rootUrl + 'Product/List/';

        } else {
            //invalid login
            $("input[name='password']").select();
            $("#validation-summary").html("Wrong email or password.");
            $scope.invalidlogin = true;
            $(btnLogin).removeClass('disabled');
            $(btnLogin).text("Submit");

        }
```

(From mvc controller)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetUser(string uname, string pword)
    {
        JBManager manager = null;

        using (SE_Context db = new SE_Context())
        {
            try
            {
                manager = db.Managers
                    .Include("Transactions.Items")
                    .Where(m => m.Username == uname && m.Password == pword)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                //At this point, manager has the desired data
                return Json(manager, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's a screenshot of the error in the browser:
[image]

Would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

UPDATE:
Everything was working fine before I used Entity Framework. (Just in case it has something to do with the issue)

Comment: First of all you need to change from HttpPost to HttpGet both in action header and in the ajax call and while returning from the action include JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet.

Comment: And how about handling the exception properly instead of "return null"?

Comment: @Rudresh Wouldn't changing the request type from POST to GET expose the username and password in the URL?

Comment: instead of returning null, return Json("")

Comment: @TigOldBitties How?

Comment: here you are requesting for a data, so ideally it should be Get Request and offcourse you can submit it has a form and verify the login credentials

Comment: @Rudresh I just tried changing the request type from POST to GET as you suggested in both action header and ajax call, but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: as a test,can you try it without `Include` part on the ef query ?

Comment: @After the switching from POST to GET, the action method is no longer executed and the browser error became status 404. Does that mean anything?

Comment: @Sampath Tried, but still getting the same result.

Comment: when you debug,is that fired the controller method ?

Comment: @Sampath Yes, the controller method gets fired and runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is nested objects.You can flatten object graphs that contain nested objects using DTOs (Data Transfer Objects).

You can just try simple example as like below.If it'll work then you need to extend it to work with your EF query.

```
public class MyDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetUser(string uname, string pword)
    {
        JBManager manager = null;

        using (SE_Context db = new SE_Context())
        {
            try
            {
               //construct the DTO here
                manager = db.Managers.Select(a=> new MyDto(
                {
                 Name = a.Name
                 })).FirstOrDefault(m => m.Username == uname && m.Password == pword);

                return Json(manager, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can read more about DTOs here : [**Create Data Transfer Objects (DTOs)**](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)

Comment: I tried reading about DTOs but I can't seem to understand its relevance to my issue. Can you give a brief explanation of how DTOs can help or at least point me to a good article about DTOs? Thanks.

Comment: I have put a reference. please see that.

Comment: any feedback for this ?